# Toad 10.6.1.3 for oracle 16-digit malformed number

Tags: sql, database, oracle, toad

I have my tableName with a 'td' field of type `number(16)`...

When I do this select

```
select *from tableName;
```

I have this:

```
5.51238080075431E15
```

Why?
How do i solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: It's a display issue.  The number is being displayed in scientific notation.

Comment: How configure Toad for view number complete? Any link? Thanks.

Comment: The real value is `5512380800754310`. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Toad's options (off of the View menu) on the Data Grids, Data page uncheck "Display large numbers in Scientific Notation"

Comment: Thanks, just for me.